# Garam masala paste for butter chicken

Tags: chicken, butter, indian-cuisine, spicy-hot

I am trying to make butter chicken and most recipes call for adding garam masala powder to the mix. 
I could not find the powder and only found garam masala paste instead.
Can i use the paste instead of the powder? 
If yes, does 1 tblsp powder equate to 1 tblsp of the paste?
Thank you!

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Garam masala powder is a spice blend, other than some anti-caking agents it's almost pure spices. Pastes are spices mixed with oil and maybe water and other ingredients like garlic, chili, pepper, tamarind, and others so they aren't an exact equivalent. Taking garam masala paste in particular if you look at [patak's](https://www.pataks.co.uk/products/garam-masala-paste.aspx) product the spices are only 23% of the total weight, the rest is water, oil, garlic powder and tamarind paste. You would need to add 4 tbsps of paste to get the same amount of spice as 1tbsp of garam masala powder, plus you will be getting extra flavors like garlic and tamarind in the mix.